# quaternions as right or left $\mathbb C$-vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, quaternions, noncommutative-algebra

I got confused when I read the question titled "Why is $\mathbb{H} \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong \text{End}_{\mathbb{C}} (\mathbb{H})$" here on this site.

I know that the OP did not specify the tensor product over which field in the main question (but he specified it in the comments of one answer), so my question, just to clarify, if we want to prove that $$\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb H \cong_{\mathbb R} M_2(C),$$

which is an isomorphism of $R$-algebras for the field of real numbers.

1- Do we have to take into account $\mathbb H$ as a left $\mathbb C$-vector space or $\mathbb H$ as a left $\mathbb C$-vector space as far as I understand there is no distinction between left and right vector spaces so why here there is a distinction?

2- Do we have to prove first the isomorphism  $\mathbb{H} \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong \text{End}_{\mathbb{C}} (\mathbb{H})$ and then prove the required isomorphism  $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb H \cong_{\mathbb R} M_2(C)$ as mentioned in the answer of @reuns?

**Here is the answer of @reuns:**

> $\Bbb{H=C+Cj}$ is a 2-dimensional complex vector space so $End_\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{H})\cong M_2(\Bbb{C})$ as complex algebras.

> Then we are willing to check that $\Bbb{H\otimes_R C }\cong M_2(\Bbb{C})$ as complex algebras, where $\Bbb{H\otimes_R C }$ comes with its own complex algebra structure.

> For this, send $1\otimes a+i\otimes b+j\otimes c+ij\otimes d$ to $a\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}+b\pmatrix{i&0\\0&-i}+c\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}+d\pmatrix{0&i\\i&0}$

3-How can we show $End_\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{H})\cong M_2(\Bbb{C})$?

Any clarification will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Also, I was looking at that question: Why is $\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{H}\cong\text{End}_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{H}$?

[Why is $\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{H}\cong\text{End}_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{H}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123709/why-is-mathbbh-otimes-mathbbh-cong-textend-mathbbr-mathbbh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what is unclear to you.

I am saying that $\Bbb{H}$ is just a 2-dimensional (left) vector space so we can replace $End_\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{H})$ by $End_\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{C}^2)$.

It means that I am interpreting $End_\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{H})$  as $$End_{left\ \Bbb{C}\ vector\ space}(\Bbb{H})$$

Then $1\otimes a+i\otimes b+j\otimes c+ij\otimes d\mapsto a\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}+b\pmatrix{i&0\\0&-i}+c\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}+d\pmatrix{0&i\\i&0}$ gives the isomorphism $\Bbb{H\otimes_R C }\to End_\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{C}^2)$.

The $i$ of $i\otimes b$, the $i$ hidden in $a=A+iB$, and the $i$ in  $\pmatrix{i&0\\0&-i}$ are not the same, that's part of the game to understand what we identity the latter two.

The distinction between left and right vector space is because $\Bbb{C}$ is a subring of $\Bbb{H}$ but which doesn't commute with $\Bbb{H}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120820/discussion-on-answer-by-reuns-quaternions-as-right-or-left-mathbb-c-vector-sp).

Comment: I do not understand your idea for proving the onto part, could you please explain more?

Comment: @mathmusic No sorry, I think it is obvious, and you don't explain what is unclear to you, so I cannot guess.

Comment: I see that you are using only one matrix from the codomain to prove surjectivity .... why you are doing that?  In $\frac{a}{2} I - i \frac{a}{2} J =  \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}  $

Where  $J = \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
0 & -i 
\end{pmatrix}$
why you used specifically $a/2$ ?and why you needed to obtain the matrix that contains $a$ and all other entries $0$ ? how did you get the matrix $J$@reuns those are the things that I do not understand..... I hope you agree to answer me now.

Comment: $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the one you wrote. It is completely obvious why we want to show the matrices with only one non-zero entry are in the image. @mathmusic

Comment: Do we have to do like this also for $b,c,d$?

Comment: Yes but it is obvious it works the same way.

Comment: what about the injective part?

Comment: obvious ${}{}{}$

Comment: Can not we prove isomorphism by dimension argument? I know that $M_2(\mathbb C)$ has 4 dimensions over $\mathbb C$ but why $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathbb H$ has 4 dimensions over $\mathbb C$ ..... you said the quaternions has $2$ dimensions over $\mathbb C$ but why in our case $\mathbb C$ has $2$ dimensions over $\mathbb C$ could you explain this please?

Comment: It is $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb H$ not $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathbb H$

Comment: $K\otimes_k A$ means that we take a $k$-vector space basis of $A$ and enlarge "formally" the coefficients to $K$, so $\dim_K(K\otimes_k A)=\dim_k(A)$. When $A$ is a $k$-algebra there is a natural $K$-algebra structure on $K\otimes_k A$.